# Android layout issue with sibling of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I add add LinearLayout with horizontal orientation to my Android layout, but unfortunately there is an error: id/title_dialog_text_view is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout.

I am trying to combine TextView and ProgressBar in horizontal not vertical line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_dialog_text_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_dialog_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_dialog_text_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/title_dialog_text_view" - The View title_dialog_text_view is inside the linear layout. So you cannot place the parent layout below child layout. Kindly remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

this error is because parent of `TextView` and `LinearLayout` are not same.
if you want to put `TextView` and `ProgressBar` horizontal , change their parent's `orientation` to `horizontal`

Comment: if it doesn't solve your problem, explain more for further helps.

Answer (score 0):

**May this solves your problem   :**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_dialog_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```